# SCARY metafunctions: why are they faster?

Tags: c++

I watched the talk and read the blog post, and I'm still unsure...why is

```
template<bool B> struct conditional { template<class T, class F> using f = T; };

template<> struct conditional<false> { template<class T, class F> using f = F; };

template<bool B, class T, class F> using conditional_t = typename conditional<B>::template f<T, F>;
```

faster to compile than

```
template<bool B, class T, class F> struct conditional { using type = T; };

template<class T, class F> struct conditional<false, T, F> { using type = F; };

template<bool B, class T, class F> using conditional_t = typename conditional<B, T, F>::type;
```

?

The first version needs to instantiate a template class with one parameter and a template alias with two, and the second version instantiates a template class with three parameters and a template alias with zero...ok, template aliases are a bit cheaper, but does it make such a big difference?

Comment: What blog post?

Comment: And which compiler?

Comment: And faster how?

Comment: After a quick Google I found https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/07/09/scary-metafunctions/, but if that's what you're talking about, please edit your question to make clear what it is that you are referring to. The phrase "the blog post" will not stand the test of time.

Comment: And which talk?

Answer (score 3):

First, I think, a little difference:

```
template<bool B, class T, class F> struct conditional;

template<class T, class F> struct conditional<false, T, F>;
```

The compiler here has to pattern match all 3 arguments against `false, T, F`.  Now this is easy, but it isn't free.

```
template<bool B> struct conditional;
template<> struct conditional<false>;
```

here it has to pattern match one argument against `false`.

So picking the specialization is strictly easier.

The next thing is the length of types generated; I find long type names lead to compiler memory use getting nasty.  `conditional<b, T, F>` in the non-SCARY case is the name of an actual unique and distinct type.  Its length is O(n) in the length of the arguments.

In the SCARY case, no new O(n) type is created.

```
typename conditional<false>::template f<T, F>;
```

this is just another name for `F`.  The type `conditional<false>` was created, it has an alias template within it, and that alias template creates no new types.  The return type is `F`, if you tried to match it against `template<class,class>class Z, class A, class B, Z<A,B>` it wouldn't match.

Finally and most importantly, memoization.  Every call to the SCARY conditional creates either `conditional<false>` or `conditional<true>`.  So the 500th time, it can do zero template specialization checking and just grab the precomputed type.

From that precomputed type, we get `template type<T,F>` alias; we apply it without memoization to get `T` or `F`.

In the non-SCARY, every distinct `T` and `F` means a different `conditional<b,T,F>` type.  So a larger memoization cache, fewer hits, and on a miss you need to run full template specialization checks to ensure nobody went and

```
template<class U> conditional<true, int, U>{using type=U;};
```

and overrode it for the specific type you are working with.